# Problem with Hudson + Git + Gitosis on windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh-agent

I have Hudson configured to connect to a Gitosis managed repository.
I am using the Git plugin.

To manually clone a repo, I need to enter my ssh pass phrase.  How can I make
Hudson aware of my passphrase? There is a version of ssh-agent that comes with
msysgit, but this is only available from git bash.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate an ssh key that does not have a passphrase, and have Hudson use that.  The point of a passphrase is to ensure that you personally are present when something uses the key -- for a server process, it doesn't make sense to have one.

The same `ssh-keygen` program that is typically used to generate an ssh key will cheerfully do so with no passphrase.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. That's what I ended up doing. But I thought it wasn't secure to have an empty passphrase. There is added protection for my setup, in that the git repo is managed by gitosis, so there is no shell access to the git repo server.